# SQL Db2 - How to unify two rows in one using datetime

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I've got a table where we have registries of employees and where they have worked. In each row, we have the employee's starting date on that place. It's something like this:

| Employee ID | Name | Branch | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 234 | 2018-01-20 |
| 1 | John Doe | 300 | 2019-03-20 |
| 1 | John Doe | 250 | 2022-01-19 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 200 | 2019-02-15 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 234 | 2020-05-20 |

I need a query where the data returned looks for the next value, making the starting date on the next branch as the end of the current. Eg:

| Employee ID | Name | Branch | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 234 | 2018-01-20 | 2019-03-20 |
| 1 | John Doe | 300 | 2019-03-20 | 2022-01-19 |
| 1 | John Doe | 250 | 2022-01-19 | --- |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 200 | 2019-02-15 | 2020-05-20 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 234 | 2020-05-20 | --- |

When there is not another register, we assume that the employee is still working on that branch, so we can leave it blank or put a default "9999-01-01" value.
Is there any way we can achieve a result like this using only SQL?

> Another approach to my problem would be a query that returns only the row that is in a range. For example, if I look for what branch John Doe worked in 2020-12-01, the query should return the row that shows the branch 300.

Comment: You may use subselect for `end_date` in the form of `(select min (start_date) from mytab t where...)` or `lead` olap function for that. Try it on your own and show what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEAD()` to peek at the next row, according to a subgroup and ordering within it.

For example:

```
select
  t.*,
  lead(start_date) over(partition by employee_id order by start_date) as end_date
from t
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay on my response.
So, I've tried your solution but I'm getting this error:

`NO AUTHORIZED LEAD NAMED  HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.19.26`

Comment: I didn't realize this was for z/OS. This query works well in DB2 LUW, and unfortunately I don't have the chance of testing it in z/OS.